# Create a row vector that contains matrix*matrix product

Tags: matlab, matrix, vector, row

I'm trying to create a least squares problem which becomes reduced to a least norm problem subject to Cx=d. I'm trying to create an array for C that requires

```
C = [A^(N-1)*B, A^(N-2)*B, A^(N-3)*B, B]
```

where the final element is just B.

`A` is a `2x2` matrix and `B` is a `2x1` matrix.

This is what I've attempted so far.

```
C = zeros(2,length(N));
for i = 1:N
    h = A.^(i-1)
    l = h.*B
    C(2,i) = l

end
```

Comment: your question is not clear enough. What exactly are you trying to do? by `least squares problem`, do you want to make a fit/solve a linear system/maximize/minimize something in a least squares sense?

Comment: I'm basically taking a system of equations and turning them into a least norm problem subject to Cx=d

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is good, there is just a minor flaw that crept into your code: `.`

```
A = rand(2);
B = rand(2,1);
N = 3

C = zeros(2,length(N));
for i = 1:N
    h = A.^(i-1); % power every element of the matrix
    l = h*B; % This is a matrix-vector multiplication
    C(2,i) = l;
end
```

Note that there is a difference between `.*` and simply `*`. The first applies the multiplication element wise -- in your case `[A(:,1)*B, A(:,2)*B]`; the second performs a [matrix-vector multiplication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication).

Now it is not clear if you indeed intended to use `A.^(i-1)`, or if you want to calculate the matrix inverse, which is written `A^(i-1)`...

Comment: Thank you, I tried using a cell array and it worked but it is unnecessary,  I attempted the code you've posted but I get the following error, "Unable to perform assignment because the size of the left side is 1-by-1 and the
size of the right side is 2-by-1."

Comment: I figured out the error, the last lines in the for loop should be c(:,i) = g; then C (:,N) = [1;1] ;

Answer (score 0):

Mathematically, since your matrix `C` can be rewritten as the following format

```
C = [A^(N-1),A^(N-2),...,A,I_2]*Kronecker(I_N,B)
```

where I_N is identity matrix with dimension N.

Then, we can use the code below to implement it

```
# create a cell array to represent [A^(N-1),A^(N-2),...,A,I], in the k^th each cell of As is the matrix A^(N-k)
As = arrayfun(@(k) A^k, [N-1:-1:0], 'UniformOutput',false);

# concatenate all matrix in As by [As{:}], then also use kron(eye(numel(As)),B) to construct the block diagonal matrix consisting of B
C = [As{:}]*kron(eye(numel(As)),B);
```

**Example with dummy data**

```
A = [1,2;3,4];
B = (1,0.5);
N = 4;
```

such that

```
C =

   64.0000   12.0000    2.0000    1.0000
  140.0000   26.0000    5.0000    0.5000
```

Comment: Thank you for the information.  Could you please explain what exactly the code is doing?

Comment: @KolacheMaster I added explanations in my code, hope it can help you understand the clue behind